# Cannot use "extension" on TypeScript's Map - declare global

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, module

I have a file, `Map.ts`, in my React project that defines an extension on the `Map` interface to enable me to map the entries of the `Map`, like this:

```
// Map.ts
export {}

declare global {
  interface Map<K, V> {
    map<T>(predicate: (key: K, value: V) => T): Map<K, T>;
  }
}

Map.prototype.map = function <K, V, T>(
  predicate: (key: K, value: V) => T
): Map<K, T> {
  let map: Map<K, T> = new Map();

  this.forEach((key: K, value: V) => {
    map.set(key, predicate(key, value));
  });

  return map;
};
```

I am unable to use this extension in my code; the `.map()` method is `undefined`.

If I include the above code in-place in the file in which `.map()` is used, it works fine. How do I get TypeScript/React/webpack/whatever to include it?

My `tsconfig.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

This is not my configuration; I have inherited it. I followed another post which suggested changing the `module` to something else I'm afraid I don't remember. In any case, it had no effect.

There doesn't appear to be anything I can export. Trying to `export` or `export default` the interface upsets the transpiler. If I put an `alert()` in there (yes, crude), it does not appear, which makes me think the file is not being included in the transpilation.

What could be going on? My understanding around modules in TS and TS config is a little ropey.

Comment: Don't make the file a module with `export {}`.

Comment: Well having a good read around and resentfully learning about modules, I have concluded it’s probably a bad idea to extend built-in objects. So I have subclassed.